# Dealing with Null Values in GraphQL API Response

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I recently got an interview task where I was required to develop a React application using a GraphQL API. The API in question is the SpaceX GraphQL API. As part of the task, I needed to retrieve specific fields such as mission name, mission patch image, launch date, and success status (boolean) for each launch.

But upon querying the API, I encountered a challenge where certain fields, notably 'launch_success' and 'mission_patch', were returning null values. After further exploration, I realized that this issue extended to other fields as well.

I've provided an example query below:

```
query Launches {
  launches {
    mission_name
    rocket {
      rocket_name
    }
    mission_id
    launch_success
  }
}
```

In this query, the `launch_success` field always returns null values, but this is not true as when I used REST API there were 80% successful launches. As I'm relatively new to GraphQL, I'm uncertain about the causes of this issue and how to fix it.

Could someone offer  any insights into why certain fields return null values and suggest potential troubleshooting steps or fixes? I would appreciate any guidance!

P.S I've already tried the same with REST API, and was able to fetch all values with no issues (interviewer provided both solutions, but I need to accomplish it with GraphQL)

Used GraphQL Playground: https://studio.apollographql.com/public/SpaceX-pxxbxen/variant/current/explorer

I attempted several strategies to retrieve the required data from the GraphQL API, including querying different fields and utilizing various query structures. Specifically, I tried querying `launch_success` from different endpoints and explored alternative fields that might provide similar information. However, in each attempt, the `launch_success` field always returned null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong at all with your GraphQL query. In GQL, it's not the case that selecting any other field can affect another. If it's `null`, it's `null` from the server's understanding.

I'm fairly confident you have found a bug in the SpaceX GQL API. The GQL schema does *not* declare this field (or many, if any at all actually) as non-nullable, meaning your application code does need to handle if those fields are `null`. However, *why* it is null when you have verified the data exists by other means can only be an issue on the SpaceX side.

This is also easily demonstrated, even without the smoking gun of having the data there in the REST API, if you grab the GQL `details` field. You then get results like:

```
{
    "details": "Engine failure at 33 seconds and loss of vehicle",
    "launch_date_utc": "2006-03-24T22:30:00.000Z",
    "launch_success": null
},
```

Which clearly shows missing data. That launch failed. This is consistent so it's reasonable to assume that there is an API issue. Coupled with the evidence about the REST API it is pretty much conclusive.

I would still build the front end code to handle all three possible values: `null` ("Unknown"), `true` ("Success") and `false` ("Failed"). Even if it never triggers the latter two with the current data sets. That would ensure you've done your job and the code would work and handle all cases if the bug was fixed on their end.

Comment: As an aside, this actually gives you an opportunity to exhibit some problem solving skills. I would explain over email ahead of time that you believe this field is erroneously null due to an issue with the SpaceX GQL api, and that there may well be a bug in the GQL API (give all of the explanation you did). Ask them to double check that matches their understanding, and then offer some workarounds that will enable you to complete the task ahead of time, like possibly mocking the value for now, or using a waterfall rest call for that field only. This shows pragmatism and a proactive approach.

Comment: For example, you could cross reference a single launch (same id) from both the REST and GQL API data and demonstrate the difference in the values. Doing this is what you would do as a good engineer in a real-life scenario. Id be impressed!

Comment: (Other candidates will have this issue, and so being the one to handle it best, not just in code but at a human & comms level, can be an unexpected bonus for you)